# Unable to install sh module and buildozer module using pip?

Tags: python

````
 ```
C:\Users\Administrator>pip install buildozer
 Collecting buildozer
Using cached buildozer-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
Collecting pexpect
Using cached pexpect-4.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Collecting sh
Using cached sh-1.14.3.tar.gz (62 kB)
    Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
````

×     python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│     exit code: 1
╰─>   [8 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-      hg1fn8lo\sh_45a7ec2824b04794ac4fe58ef669a78f\setup.py", line 5, in 
import sh
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-    hg1fn8lo\sh_45a7ec2824b04794ac4fe58ef669a78f\sh.py", line 37, in 
import fcntl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
[end of output]

note:    This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

×      Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─>     See above for output.

```
  note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

 

: See above for details. '''

'''
   Check and suggest the solution.
   C:\Users\Administrator>pip list
      Package            Version
   ------------------ ---------
     certifi            2022.9.24
   charset-normalizer 2.1.1
  docutils           0.19
     ez-setup           0.9
  idna               3.4
  Kivy               2.1.0
  kivy-deps.angle    0.3.2
  kivy-deps.glew     0.3.1
  kivy-deps.sdl2     0.4.5
  Kivy-Garden        0.1.5
  pip                22.3
  Pygments           2.13.0
  pypiwin32          223
  pywin32            304
  requests           2.28.1
     setuptools         65.5.0
  supertools         1.0.1
  urllib3            1.26.12
    '''
```

Comment: fcntl package that is required during the installation of "sh" is available only on unix/posix platforms and you are installing on windows.  EG: this will not work in windows..

Comment: ok..thanks for early response..whats d other way to develop apps using python in windows?

Comment: Maybe you could just use WSL ?